# C++ Doubly linked list printing

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I have some difficulties with doubly-linked list class, which is a part of my university project. Code of the class is like this:

```
class container
{
public:
    class node
    {
        public:
        node * prev;
        node * next;
        int value;
    };

container(int v);

node *start; // first element of the list
node *finish; // last element of the list
void insert_start(node *start, int val);
void print_container(); 
}
```

Function insert_start should add element to the beginning of the list. Code is as follows:

```
void container :: insert_start(node *start, int val)
{
    if(start!=NULL)
    {
        cout << "in insert_start" << endl;
        cout << "number added:" << val << endl;

        node *element = new node;

        element->value=val;
        element->next=start;
        start=element;
        start->prev=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "List is empty" << endl;
    }
}
```

And function print_container should print my linked list. Code looks like this:

```
void container::print_container()
{
    node *tmp;
    tmp = start;
    while(tmp!=nullptr)
    {
        cout << tmp->value << endl;
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there are two problems with my program. Firstly, it 
seems to add the same random value in added elements of data structure.  Secondly, there is a segmentation fault during executing function print_container. I suppose it might be a bug(or bugs) in insert_start function, but I am not completely sure about that.

Here is test program:

```
int main(void)
{
    int how_many_pieces;

    container L(6);

    L.insert_finish(L.finish,3);
    cout << "added element: " << L.finish->value << endl;

    L.insert_start(L.start,8);
    cout << "added element: " << L.start->value << endl;

    L.insert_start(L.start,12);
    cout << "added element: " << L.start->value << endl;


   //show elements of the L list
   L.print_container();
   cout << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't pass in the node as a parameter - you don't need to. The container class can already see the start and finish nodes, and passing them in just confuses things.

Second, you should make these private so that anyone using the class must use your insert_start or insert_finish functions.

The new class will look like this:

```
class container
{
    private:
        class node
        {
            public:
            node * prev;
            node * next;
            int value;
        };

        node *start; // first element of the list
        node *finish; // last element of the list

    public:
        container(int v);

        void insert_start(int val);
        void print_container();
};
```

Third, make sure you set the links for each direction. For example, in your insert_start function:

```
node *element = new node;

element->value = val;
element->next = start;
element->prev = NULL;
start->prev = element; //This part was missing
start = element;
```

Without referring your original node back to the new one, you're treating it as a normal, singly-linked list. If you want the traversal flexibility that a doubly-linked list offers, you need to set up the links correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
void container :: insert_start(node *start, int val)
{
    if(start!=NULL)
```

which `start` is the last line supposed to refer to?  Is it checking the parameter value, or the public class value?

Also, if the list is empty, you probably want to do something other than print a message.  The list has to begin *somehow*.

---

(addendum)

There are at least two ways to prevent this problem.  I'll show three at once:

```
void container :: insert_start(node *node_to_insert, int val)
{
    if (this->start != NULL)  // is list not empty?
```

It looks almost the same, right?

- The formal parameter name now indicates its meaning.  The name suggests that the node pointed to is to be added to the list.
- Object instance values are accessed through the `this` keyword.  This disambiguates the scope of identically named variables syntactically and really helps a programmer to easily spot what is what.
- The comment clarifies the high level intent of the statement which makes it easy for anyone checking the code to identify a possible discrepancy.
- Parameter names no longer match object member names.  While it is often useful to have the names parallel each other (`p_x, p_y, p_z` for three parameter values to initialize member variables `x, y, z`) they really should be kept distinct for simplicity and clarity.

Comment: Public class value. I wanted node *start to be visible for all functions in class container without complications with access to this node. Probably there are better, safer and nicer ways to do it, but i'm not very advanced in c++ yet and I want to write working container class at first.  Anyway, thanks for your help.